# Edit open file limit for SysV service in CentOS 7

Tags: systemd

I want to change open file limit for a Riak service in CentOS 7. The problem is that Riak still uses SysV init script.

According to [docs](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/System_Administrators_Guide/sect-Managing_Services_with_systemd-Unit_Files.html) i have to create `/etc/systemd/system/riak.d/NAME.conf` and set the parameter there. Then reload systemd and the service.

```
 # In /etc/systemd/system/riak.d/limits.conf
 [Service]
 LimitNOFILE=65536
```

But this has no effect:

```
$ systemctl show riak -p LimitNOFILE 
LimitNOFILE=4096
```

What did I do wrong? Does this work for SysV init scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need `riak.service.d`, not `riak.d`.